# What type of URL is this- 'http://goo.gl/7nQT9g'?

Tags: url

I usually found this type URLs in facebook. They are different from the commonly seen type of URLs. What type of URL is it ? What is 'goo' and '.gl' means ?

Another type of such type is - http://bit.ly/1jUkvIL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ".gl" is the country code top level domain (ccTLD) of Greenland. All recognized countries and some partially recognized ones, like Taiwan (.tw), are assigned these for their national uses. The United States has .gov and .mil for themselves because of the origins of the DNS system, but also .us. See for example the Forest Service website: http://www.fs.fed.us/

If you want to play around, see Wikipedia's template of all of them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:CcTLD

Because they cut off one character from the usual three letter TLDs (.com, .org, etc.) they are valued by these URL shorteners (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortener) for use in places like Twitter that require severe economization of character.

The use of them to spell out names (bitly, googl[e], etc.) is sometimes known as a domain hack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_hack

Answer (score 5):

It is a [shortened URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening).

> URL shortening is a technique on the World Wide Web in which a Uniform
>   Resource Locator (URL) may be made substantially shorter in length and
>   still direct to the required page. This is achieved by using an HTTP
>   Redirect on a domain name that is short, which links to the web page
>   that has a long URL.
>
> For example, the URL
>   "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening" can be shortened to
>   "http://bit.ly/urlwiki", "http://tinyurl.com/urlwiki",
>   "http://is.gd/urlwiki" or "http://goo.gl/Gmzqv". This is especially
>   convenient for messaging technologies such as Twitter and Identi.ca
>   which severely limit the number of characters that may be used in a
>   message. Short URLs allow otherwise long web addresses to be referred
>   to in a tweet. In November 2009, the shortened links of the URL
>   shortening service Bitly were accessed 2.1 billion times.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening)